# Opening an Access database on Windows 7

Tags: ms-access

I'm getting the following error message on some users machines:

> The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: There is an invalid use of the . (dot) or ! operator or invalid parentheses.

This error message appears when trying to open the Access database on some peoples' machines using Access 2010 on Windows 7 from a shared location.

Using the same shared network location the database opens fine on Windows XP with Access 2003.

I've checked the registry for the Sandboxmode (2).

The folder location is shared and open for all users.

Looks from the code its not liking the main menu, its complaining about the ! in this form:

```
strCriteria = [Forms]![MainMenu]![Text22]
```

Comment: With no code, no details, and no access to the systems, how exactly would you like us to help you? We can't see what "expression On Open you entered as the event property setting" from here (presumably you can see it from there, because you entered it. :-) Questions that ask for speculation on all the things that could cause your app not to run or database not to open are not appropriate here. Questions here need to be specific, and asking "What could possibly be wrong?" isn't specific at all.

Comment: Just to confirm: When you say that users are opening a database "from a shared location" do you mean that there is an `.mdb` file on a network share and multiple users are opening that file directly?

Comment: Yeah thats correct, well an .mde file which points to a .mdb

Comment: @Ken white, I know its not specific but I just thought if someone else had come across this same issue they may be able to help!

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. If it did, I could post a question about a noise my car is making, and say "I know it's not right for this site, but I was just hoping someone else had the same problem and might be able to help." Questions should follow the guidelines here. :-)

Comment: (Ken & Stan, I see comment arguments like that all the time.  This was one of the few that made me laugh.)  @Stan, go to Tools->References.  Are there any missing references?

Comment: Yeah no missing references

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues here:

1. Compiled `.mde` (and `.accde`) files are a lot more "fussy" about different versions of Access than `.mdb` (and `.accdb`) files are. This is presumably because `.mde` files have the source code stripped out of them so Access cannot re-compile things "on the fly" like it can with an `.mdb` file. Years ago I began stipulating that if the Access application is using an `.mde` front-end then all users must be running the same version of Access and the `.mde` must be compiled for that version. Even so, an `.mde` file will occasionally "act up" but re-building the `.mde` from the source `.mdb` will usually fix it. (Subtle changes introduced by Office patches and Service Packs may account for at least some of that.)
2. If multiple concurrent users are opening the **same** `.mde` file from a network folder then you will almost certainly encounter problems. For many years it has been well-known among Access developers that a multi-user Access application **must** be split into a front-end and a back-end (which you have apparently done), and each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end file. Even Microsoft is recommending the practice now (after many years of their being conspicuously silent about the matter).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll try re-creating the .mde using access 2010 and see if this solves any of the issues and create a local copy for each of the users.